# How can we use two different Magento 2 Versions/Instances installed using Docker?

Tags: docker, magento, docker-compose

I have installed Docker Image for Magento 2 and it is working fine. I need two different Magento Versions i.e Magento 2.1.13 and Magento 2.3.0 working simultaneously on my system.

How can I install 2nd Magento 2 instance using Docker ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish them on different ports, like this:

`docker run -p 8080:80 YourMagentoImage1`

`docker run -p 8081:80 YourMagentoImage2`

Finally you could use a reverse proxy to access both from your browser over port 80.

*Note that I don't know the actual Port your Magento uses, 80 is an example.*